# Why doesn't the $.post appear to be working on an iPad/iPhone on my site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad, debugging, qtip

[This](http://wncba.co.uk/results/?action=navigate&season=2012&league_id=3&division_id=14&fixture_id=2444&nav_key=4bb9400fb779ddf686dea09070519589) is one of the pages.

When you click on the error icon at the bottom of the table more appear in the table. Then when you click on an icon in the table a qtip popup appears and grabs a code through the jquery function $.post. I've tested it in IE, Chrome, Opera and Firefox and it works fine. In safari on the ipod/ipad it doesn't though and then developer console on the device isn't really very helpful. The one thing that appears in it (twice) is:

---

```
JavaScript: Error
undefined
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function
```

---

Anyone know what might be triggering this and if this relates to why the ajax isn't working? The script that's included relating to all this is [here](http://wncba.co.uk/results/javascript/error-reportingv2.js).

Thanks.

---

**Edit:** This is a part of the code that I've now changed to fix it. It's gone from

```
$.post("ajax_requests.php?action=get_error_code", {data:$(this.targetThis).attr('data-errorData')}, function(data) {

    $(this.qtipThis).find('.code').html(data);

    $(this.qtipThis).find('.email .link').attr('onclick', '');
    $(this.qtipThis).find('.email .link').attr('href', 'mailto:'+errorReportEmail+'?subject=Website Table Error (Error id: '+data+')');

}.bind(this));
```

to this (thanks to @raina77ow 's answer)

```
    var self = this;
    $.post("ajax_requests.php?action=get_error_code", {data:$(this.targetThis).attr('data-errorData')}, function(data) {

    $(self.qtipThis).find('.code').html(data);

    $(self.qtipThis).find('.email .link').attr('onclick', '');
    $(self.qtipThis).find('.email .link').attr('href', 'mailto:'+errorReportEmail+'?subject=Website Table Error (Error id: '+data+')');
});
```

Comment: I've had a problem with the minified version of jquery on mobile devices once (i think it threw a similar error). try changing it to the full one to see if that fixes it.

Comment: I've changed I'm afraid it's still throwing the same error :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the problem is related to the `$.post`, may be it's because of some variation of [this issue](https://github.com/Shopify/batman/issues/189)? It's not about `batman`, it's about Function.bind() method.

Comment: That's it! It works now. I've changed it so that instead of the `.bind` it creates `var self=this` and uses that instead. Thanks :)

Comment: It also fixed the other problem as well where the 'click here' link on the first qtip wasn't working.